# Is it possible to have a two head arrow as a decorator?

Tags: arrows, decorations

I would like to have the analogue of `\overrightarrow{x}` but with a two headed arrow (as in `\twoheadrightarrow`, but above the variable). Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\Overrightarrow#1{\mathrlap{\overrightarrow{\phantom{#1\mkern11mu}}}%
  \overrightarrow{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\Overrightarrow{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, and the `\mathrlap` is a keeper!

Answer (score 3):

In the MWE below, the user command to create double-right-pointing arrow accents is `\overdoublerightarrow`. Its definition uses the LaTeX commands `\overset` and `\DeclareMathSymbol` and relies on the fact that the double-right arrow resides in slot "10 of the AMSa symbols. (The precise definitions may be found in the file `amssymb.sty`.) Finally, I use the command `\textstyle` because the default style of accent symbols is `\scriptstyle`, which looks much too skinny.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Doublerightarrow}{\mathalpha}{AMSa}{"10}
\newcommand\overdoublerightarrow[1]{%
   \overset{\textstyle\Doublerightarrow}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\overrightarrow{z}$ $\overrightarrow{A}$

$\overdoublerightarrow{z}$ $\overdoublerightarrow{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However it does not help me - I am looking for the analogue of `\twoheadrightarrow` (two arrowheads on the right) and not of `\leftrightarrow` (one arrowhead on each side).

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood what you meant to say by "twoheaded" arrows. (I thought you wanted one arrowhead each going in two directions, rather than two arrowheads pointing in the same direction.) Let me change my answer.

Comment: I've now succeeded in redoing my answer. Sorry for the delay -- my ISP's service was down for several hours. :-(

Comment: Glad you like it! Just remember: if you want to make the arrows *just a bit* smaller than they appear in the answer above, just remove the `\textstyle` instruction; if you want to make them *a lot* smaller, replace `\textstyle` with `scriptscriptstyle`. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @Mico Can you please tell me how to get the equivalent of `\leftrightarrow{}`?

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney - I assume you've already come across `$\overleftrightarrow{z}$` and decided that the arrow symbol looks *much too big*. According to my taste, the arrow symbol in `$\overset{\leftrightarrow}{z}$` is also too big. I'd probably go with `\newcommand\overlrarrow[1]{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\leftrightarrow}{#1}}` and then write `$\overlrarrow{z}$` and `$\overlrarrow{Z}$`. BTW, in case you haven't done so already, try loading the [old-arrows](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/old-arrows) package and see (pun intended) if you like the result -- smaller, crisp-looking arrow heads!